# dependencies checked into git repository - composer install changed a lot of files - don't want to check them in or remove them

Tags: git, github

I am working on a project that I didn't create. After installing it on my local system and running composer install and npm install, I end up with 1700+ files changed. I believe that if I would commit them, it would screw up our staging environment. Please correct me if I am wrong.

I can't exclude them with `.gitignore` since they are checked in. How can I hide them in git without removing them from my local system and not changing/removing them in the repository?

Comment: Why are those files in the repository in the first place?

Comment: Why would it screw up your staging environment? I would assume you have CD in place to deploy your software properly, including running composer install and npm install to get the right version of all dependencies. If not, and you have now changed the version numbers, as an example, but don't commit the changes to the dependencies, your code is written against version X but you deploy version Y, wouldn't *that* screw up staging?

Comment: I didn't set up the project. So it wasn't my decision to commit those files. Still pretty new to git and also not very familiar with composer and npm.

Comment: A general rule—which may or may not apply in your specific case—is that a Git repository should never store any *computer generated* files, as Git is aimed at storing files that humans poke code into. If a program like `composer install` or `npm install` installs something that you didn't write yourself, those don't go in the repository. (There are various exceptions for "vendored" files in some systems, though.) Under these rules you would not have those files in Git so this would not have come up in the first place...

Comment: My advice would be to talk to the main maintainer of the repository, and ask them for advice.